# Putting in precedence in the where clause by using ez_where plugin for ruby on rails.

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, logic, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am working on a project which used this [plugin](https://github.com/ezmobius/ez-where/blob/master/README.txtso). I really can't use any other plugin to do what I have to do.

I am using this to build a WHERE clause in my query, which is otherwise built. Here's how I am doing it:

```
cond = EZ::Where::Condition.new
if first_condition
  cond.append "A > B"
end
if second_condition
  cond.append "C < D"
end
if third_condition
  cond.or "E > F"
  cond.or "G > H"
end
```

The issue is that any combitions of the first, second or third conditions can be true. But in every case, my query is supposed to be like this:

```
Where A > B AND C < D AND (E > F OR G > H)
```

And if Only first and third condition is true then:

```
Where A > B AND (E > F OR G > H)
```

How do I do it in ez_where plugin for ruby on rails? Or if not that, how do I do that at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cond = EZ::Where::Condition.new
if first_condition
  cond.append "A > B"
end
if second_condition
  cond.append "C < D"
end
if third_condition
  cond.or "E > F"
  cond.or "G > H"
end
```

I just realized a really easy way of doing the above would be

```
cond1 = EZ::Where::Condition.new
if first_condition
  cond1.append "A > B"
end
if second_condition
  cond1.append "C < D"
end
cond2 = EZ::Where::Condition.new
if third_condition
  cond2.or "E > F"
  cond2.or "G > H"
end
cond = EZ::Where::Condition.new
cond.append cond
```